# Django: Create a form for another other user existing in DB. ('Users' object has no attribute 'get')

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a cloud panel for our cloud Database, and I'm having some issues by creating a form for other users and rendering it.

This is my `forms.py`

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from main.models import Users


class UsersForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['last_login']
```

And then inside the `views.py`, I'm trying to create a form for other user with:

```
form = UsersForm(model)
return render(request, 'service_desk/ticket_list_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

I'm trying to pass in the user model to the form, but as you can see I'm getting an error

Comment: you should use `form=UsersForm()` for new users and `form=UsersForm(instance=Users.objects.get(pk=...))` for old one

Comment: Thank you, this method works correctly!